# What shell command might I use to open the last alphanumeric file in a directory?

Tags: shell, command, zsh

I have log files that are auto generated and organized in a directory as such:

- logs/laravel-2015-07-01.log
- logs/laravel-2015-07-02.log
- logs/laravel-2015-07-03.log
- logs/laravel-2015-07-04.log
- logs/laravel-2015-07-05.log

I want to create a shell alias that prints out the tail of the latest log file (laravel-2015-07-05.log at the moment).

```
alias plog="tail ___________________________"
```

What can I fill in the blank to select the latest log file?

A new log file is generated each day and the date string pattern should be apparent. The server timezone where the files are generated is not the same as my local timezone, so the solution that I'm looking for would find the log file with the latest date (not necessarily just today's date).

Comment: `ls -t` will sort entries by modified time. Incidentally, this post probably belongs on superusers, or something similar, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are the only files in this directory and follow the strict naming format

```
laravel-yyyy-mm-dd
```

then can run ( in the log directory )

**view last log tail**

```
ls | tail -n 1 | xargs tail
```

this uses the default alphabetical sort order of ls

can adjust this if outside directory to run :

```
ls -d logs/* | tail -n 1 | xargs tail
```

Comment: That's perfect, but how can I make this for a specific directory? I tried

ls ~/some_path/logs | tail -n 1 | xargs tail

But that gave me "tail: laravel-2015-07-05.log: No such file or directory" I'm guessing I need to have the path at the end too somehow?

Comment: `ls -d ~/some_path/logs/* | tail -n 1 | xargs tail` will work

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use Micah Elliot's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Zsh has “glob qualifiers” for this. Look for that section in `man zshexpn`. No need for pipes, ls, xargs, etc.

```
tail logs/*(.om[1])
```

This says to look for:

- `*` all
- `.` files
- `o` ordered ascending
- `m` by modified time
- `[1]` and take only the newest one

Then your alias becomes:

```
alias plog='tail logs/*(.om[1])'
```

Or, if you prefer thinking of it in the reverse (take the last as newest, like `tail -1`), use `O` (to reverse order) and `[-1]` (for last):

```
tail logs/*(.Om[-1])
```